# What is the best way to validate that a foreign key is valid with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am trying with something like this:

```
 @NotNull
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "source_id")
 private TransactionSource transactionSource;
```

and when the source id to create this class is invalid it throws a PSQLException

I want to return a Bad Request Status with a message with somenthing like "source id does not exist"

Comment: Given this should happen very infrequently, you could catch and throw a suitable exception (that presumably gets converted to 400 by your controller). You could throw a hibernate ConstraintViolationException which will look like a validation failure.